# crontab file contents missing or in different place?

Tags: arch-linux, cron

I'm using Arch Linux. Before today, when I ran `crontab -e` or `sudo crontab -e`, I would see the default contents of the crontab file opened in nano. But now when I run `crontab -e` I see a blank file `/tmp/crontab.wFM7eq`.

What could have happened and how do I get back my old crontab file?

Answer (score 0):

The /tmp/crontab.wFM7eq file is just the temporary buffer you're editing, once you've saved it in the editor, it will become the new crontab-file for the user you're editing for.

The first time you edit a user's crontab-file, it typically will be empty (or contain a comment about the various fields).  So if this was the first time using `crontab -e` for this user, this is correct behavior.  Once something had been added, this will show the next time you edit the file.

The master-crontab file - /etc/crontab - you probably must edit manually with `sudo nano /etc/crontab` (remember that what is in /etc/crontab.d is "added" to the /etc/crontab).

Comment: Hm, but before today I would see a file showing the commented-out explanation of the crontab file. It's gone now.